# What are the problems with my birthdate sorting runner program?

Tags: java

This program's goal is to sort the list of people based on their birthdate.

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class Person implements Comparable<Person>
{
  private int myYear;
  private int myMonth;
  private int myDay;
  private String myName;

  public Person( int y, int m, int d, String n)
  {
      myYear=y;
      myMonth=m;
      myDay=d;

  }

  public int compareTo( Person other )
  {
      if(other.myYear>this.myYear)
          return 1;
      if(other.myYear<this.myYear)
          return -1;
      if(other.myMonth>this.myMonth)
          return 1;
      if(other.myMonth<this.myMonth)
          return -1;
      if(other.myDay>this.myDay)
          return 1;
      if(other.myDay<this.myDay)
          return -1;
      return(other.compareTo(this.myName));
  }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" + "myYear=" + myYear + ", myMonth=" + myMonth + ", myDay=" + myDay + ", myName=" + myName + '}';
    }


}
}
```

Here's the runner in which I'm having trouble with... All it's returning is [].

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import static java.lang.System.*;

    public class PersonRunner
    {
        public static void main ( String[] args ) throws IOException
        {

                Scanner person=new Scanner("person.dat");
                ArrayList list=new ArrayList();
                ArrayList list2=new ArrayList();
                person.nextLine();
                while(person.hasNextLine()){
                   list.add(new Person(person.nextInt(),person.nextInt(),person.nextInt(),person.next()));
                }
                list2=list;
                for(int i=0;i<list.size()-1;i++){
                    if(list.get(i).compareTo(list.get(i+1)))==1){
                    list2[i].set(list.get(i));
                }
            }
                System.out.println(list2);
        }
    }
```

There is a main .dat file in which it's reading from, where the test cases/info is listed...

```
12
50 20 10 MARK
10 40 20 JACK
50 30 3 JAMES
3 50 2 JOANN
10 40 20 TOMMY
40 90 11 ANN
3 50 2 SALLY
3 50 5 FRED
11 11 11 DOUG
5 25 50 ED
10 10 1 ELTON
1 1 3 LINH
```

Help would be appreciated.I'm doing this problem for a class, so all I want is basic coding help, it shouldn't be anything too advanced... Thank you all for your answers.

Comment: `Collections.sort`?

Comment: I am guessing that in your case `3` is `2003` but `50` is `1950`?

Comment: Is this data really supposed to represent birthdays? I am unaware of any month or day of month that is '40' like in case 2. The input takes it as year/month/day, but that doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: They may be typos in the posting, but: a) `myName` is never set in the `Person` constructor; b)the last return in the `compareTo` should be probably be `return (this.myName.compareTo(other.myName));`, but it depends upon which way the sort is supposed to go.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so you have a bunch of compiler and logic errors...

## Starting with...

```
if(list.get(i).compareTo(list.get(i+1)))==1){
```

is wrong, the `==1)` is outside of the context of the `if (...)` block, you have one two many closing brackets.

It's also wrong because `get` is going to return an `Object` which doesn't have a `compareTo` method.

You also seem to have an extra `}` bracket at the end of the code, which is going to screw everything up.

## Next...

```
public Person(int y, int m, int d, String n) {
    myYear = y;
    myMonth = m;
    myDay = d;
}
```

You never assign `n` o `myName` which is going to cause a potential `NullPointerException`.

## Next...

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner("person.dat");
```

Is going to create a `Scanner` which is going to parse the `String` `person.dat` and not load the file.

There's probably a few others, but to be honest, I threw a lot go it away.

## Next...

```
return (other.compareTo(this.myName));
```

is wrong as you are trying to compare an instance of `Person` with a `String`, it should be...

```
return (other.myName.compareTo(this.myName));
```

## Can we fix it?

Let's start with the `Scanner`.  You need to be more specific about the source of the data you want the `Scanner` to use.  In this case, you want to read the contents of a `File`...

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("person.dat"));
```

Next, make use of the generic support in Java to provide more context to the contents of your `List`s...

```
ArrayList<Person> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

This will make it easier to manage and you won't need to cast the object as your retrieve it from the `List`

Personally, I would read each line of the file and use a second `Scanner` to parse the individual lines.

```
while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
  String text = reader.nextLine();
  Scanner parser = new Scanner(text);
  list.add(new Person(parser.nextInt(), parser.nextInt(), parser.nextInt(), parser.next()));
}
```

To be honest, I have no idea what...

```
list2=list;
for(int i=0;i<list.size()-1;i++){
    if(list.get(i).compareTo(list.get(i+1)))==1){
    list2[i].set(list.get(i));
}
```

this is doing, and since there is an easier way to perform it, I just removed it and replaced it with...

```
Collections.sort(list);
for (Person p : list) {
    System.out.println(p);
}
```

And the updated `Person` class...

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {

  private int myYear;
  private int myMonth;
  private int myDay;
  private String myName;

  public Person(int y, int m, int d, String n) {
    myYear = y;
    myMonth = m;
    myDay = d;
    myName = n;
  }

  public int compareTo(Person other) {
    if (other.myYear > this.myYear) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (other.myYear < this.myYear) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (other.myMonth > this.myMonth) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (other.myMonth < this.myMonth) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (other.myDay > this.myDay) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (other.myDay < this.myDay) {
      return -1;
    }
    return (other.myName.compareTo(this.myName));
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Person{" + "myYear=" + myYear + ", myMonth=" + myMonth + ", myDay=" + myDay + ", myName=" + myName + '}';
  }

}
```